# Retrieving User Profile Properties Values in visual webpart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile-property

In SharePoint 2010, I have created a custom user profile property named "MyCustomTools" in central admin as user Administrator.

Then I went to central admin and edit user profile and added vales in "MyCustomTools" as "Google;Facebook".

Now I want to retrieve values of custom properties like Google as link with url and Facebook as link with url. I am able to retrieve custom property name using below code:

```
new protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("servername"))
            {
                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                ProfileSubtypeManager psm = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(context);
                ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype(ProfileSubtypeManager.GetDefaultProfileName(ProfileType.User));
                //Get the properties
                ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = ps.Properties;
                foreach (ProfileSubtypeProperty profileSubtypeProperty in pspm.PropertiesWithSection)
                {
                    if (profileSubtypeProperty.Name == "MyCustomTools")
                    {
                        Label1.Text += profileSubtypeProperty.Name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but I need to retrieve values.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value is pretty straight forward though this is best answered by looking at the [code in this other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28034/how-to-get-user-profile-property-value-when-privacy-for-property-set-to-private) on this forum. That question is a little bit different from this one but provides a good example.

The `.Value` property will return a [UserProfileValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilevaluecollection.aspx) that you can iterate through to get the individual values.