# Custom user profile property returns null value

Tags: 2013, user-profile-property, visual-studio-2012

I am accessing the user profile property from code but it returns null value as well as false in the boolean type property.

My code is:

```
if (web != null)
{

    SPList list = ListHelper.GetListByUrl(web.Lists,ListNames.DepartmentsUrl);


    if (list != null)
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = string.Format(CamlQueries.Department.QueryForDepartmentUrl, properties.Web.Name);
        SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(query);

        if (coll != null)
        {
            SPListItem item = coll[0];
            var taxonomyField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Department) as TaxonomyField;
            var fieldValue = item[taxonomyField.Id] as TaxonomyFieldValue;
            SPServiceContext contex = SPServiceContext.GetContext(properties.Web.Site);
            if (contex != null)
            {
                 UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(contex);
                 #region Change User Profile Properties
                 if (upm != null)
                 {

                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                                {
                            UserProfile u = upm.GetUserProfile(user[0]);

                            if ((bool)u[FieldNames.Manager].Value)
                            {
                             properties.ErrorMessage = "Manager is already assigned to other department";
                            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                            properties.Cancel = true;




                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (groupAdded.Name.EndsWith(UserGroups.Managers.Name))
                                     ....
```

Here in the condition :`if ((bool)u[FieldNames.Manager].Value)` I am getting false but in the user profile property from central admin it is true.

What should I do?

N.B. The property's privacy is set to Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
u[PropertyConstants.Manager].Value; instead of u[FieldNames.Manager].Value .

Else [How to get user profile property value when privacy for property set to "Private" (only me)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28034/how-to-get-user-profile-property-value-when-privacy-for-property-set-to-private)

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, but the `[FieldNames.Manager]` returns the name of the custom property of user profile. So how would I get that custom property in property. Actually manager is boolean in my case

Comment: Not sure i understood you correctly . But I have a bool custom property  ABCD-DEFGFG with Display Name as ABC .I use the below code .                            UserProfileValueCollection valuesr = profile["ABCD-DEFGFG"];
                                bool VOlla = (bool)valuesr.Value;
                                if (VOlla)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else{
                                }

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to add "AllowUnsafeUpdates" in your code. Adding this might help.

```
 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=true;
 web.Update();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I see no updates being made, how will this help?